# UC3843 voltage drop problem

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

I have assembled the following circuit.
In no-load mode and even up to 0.5 A current everything is fine, but when more load is placed on the circuit, the voltage drops to 2.5 V.

If I reduce the value of R6, the situation will be a little better and finally the output will reach 7 V.

I have been working on it for almost a month and I have raised it in various forums, but there has been no result.

During the voltage drop, the feedback pin has about 0.1 V, but in the no-load state, it has 2.5 V.
For input, I use a 25 V 15 A power supply.

The model of the core is T157-26, on which there are two coils of 10 turns. Its value is 10 uH.

Unfortunately, I do not have a scope.

Please help me solve this problem.

[image]

I got a cheap oscilloscope model to make it easier to work with, assembled this circuit, tested it with an oscilloscope. I only add a 7815 regulator and a 100 ohm resistor for pin7, because I wanted my input to be 27V. The problem is that the MOSFET With a load of about 2 amps, it gets very hot and I have a severe voltage drop. For example, with a load of 3.5 amps (lamp), the output voltage drops by 10 volts. 3.9 Ohm resistance of 30 watts to the output, the output voltage and current reached 8.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the complete schematic
[image]

At first, all parts were on fiber.
And exactly the same problems existed now.
In order to change some parts more easily, I brought the control part to the board.
Because of this, the IC socket remains on the fiber, but its connections are disconnected
There is a photo of two other cores next to the circuit with which I have tested the circuit
One is 15 and the other is 40 microhenries.
The MOSFET was also broken, it has been removed for replacement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! _”Unfortunately, I do not have a scope”_ There’s your problem. What does your layout look like?

Comment: Oh yuck, heh, even as big as T157, that poor thing is gonna get toasty. #26 powdered iron is NOT made for DCM. Also, C5-R2 should be in series, not parallel -- I don't know why all the appnotes have it the worse way around. (This doesn't affect your present problem, most likely, but affects output voltage regulation / precision.) And yep, almost useless without layout and waveforms -- show everything you can!

Comment: R6 is the current limit sensor, so it's probably causing an overcurrent shutdown. But that could be caused by inductance in the resistor, or the primary of transformer X1 may be saturating. That should be observable on a scope.

Comment: Try simulating your circuit like the pros.

Comment: I simulated with Proteus and Multisim software.
Unfortunately, Proteus does not support this chip at all, and Multisim  does not work either

Comment: Try webench simulator from TI

Comment: Is this oscilloscope suitable for this work?   https://www.amazon.com/DSO138-Oscilloscope-Digital-Handheld-Version/dp/B088FWHKZG

Comment: You say "I only add a 7815 regulator and a 100 ohm resistor for pin7" but they aren't on your schematic.  So we don't know what you're describing.  A photo of the circuit might also give clues.

Comment: Post layout please.

Comment: @winny - Do you mean the plan behind the fiber?
I don't have it on a computer
Based on this schematic, I assembled it with thick and strong soldering

Comment: @jonathanjo - Thank you very much
I put the schematic that I have assembled

Comment: _And a photo of the circuit as constructed._  Come on friend, if you're asking about a circuit which doesn't work, you have to show it!

Comment: Where did you find the original schematic? Perhaps there is some discussion there that might be useful.

Comment: Plan behind the fiber? _”I assembled it with thick and strong soldering”_ Please tell me the circuit it made on a PCB and not a breadboard.

Comment: Is the original circuit drawn in some strange way or what’s up with the C8-C9 flying capacitor configuration? Some odd flyback configuration I’ve never seen?

Comment: Well, some thoughts: it seems _extremely_ strange to put a linear regulator in front of a switching converter ... a 7815 is rated at 1 A but you want 3 A of load ... what's the 100R resistor doing? ... The UC 3843 is rated for 30V input, why don't you connect it to your 27V?

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy - in this link
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wsVshsJ11o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wsVshsJ11o)

Comment: @winny - Thank you for your attention. If you search a little, you will find many schematics similar to this one, although with minor changes

Comment: @jonathanjo - I used the regulator to protect the MOSFET
Because Vgs=+-20 V
Please explain why I need 3 amps

Comment: This UC3843 current mode switching device is rather finicky about layout, especially at higher currents, so your perf board and proto board assemblies are bound to have problems. I had thought the output drive was limited to 15V, but it is actually determined by Vcc, so your 7812 regulator is needed.

Comment: Oh no, breadboard. This circuit it bound to fail. You need to design a PCB for it with proper solid ground plane and strong decoupling.

Comment: The scope traces seem to show a frequency of 16 kHz or 24 kHz, whereas the 8.2k resistor and 2.2 nF capacitor should give 100 kHz. I think your inductor is saturating at these low frequencies. And why are they not corresponding to the RC values?

Comment: **you** said "with a load of 3.5 amps".

Comment: @PStechPaul - Thank you for your explanation
I have also tested the circuit with 7812
But it has not affected the problem
I have to say about the frequency, I changed the value of some parts for testing
For example, the same resistance to 15 kilos and the capacitor to 4.7 nanofarads
On the other hand, I did not know about the settings of the oscilloscope
Maybe the differences are because of that
I have a question
In the oscilloscope photos, isn't the fall time of the MOSFET (gate-ground with load) too long?

Comment: @winny - I have explained in my question.
Previously the circuit was as you recommended
And it had no effect on the problem.
For ease of testing and changing some values if needed, I assembled it like this.

Comment: @jonathanjo - The regulator is only used for IC power supply.
Power supply has not changed

Comment: “On fiber” = perfboard. A perfboard is not a real PCB and lacks ground plane. This circuit (any switcher really) won’t work without one. Start a PCB layout in your eCAD of choice and send for production or etch it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit has quite a number of difficulties, as given in the comments by many people.

### If you want a power supply

My suggestion is: **start again from scratch**, paying attention the following:

1. What output is required?  Voltage and current.
2. What input is available and suitable?  Voltage in particular.
3. Find a circuit *designed for these parameters*
4. Build it, paying close attention to any layout requirements.

You will see that the [UC3843 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3843.pdf) has two pages of instructions about layout:

[image]

### If you want an electronics project

If on the other hand you're building a circuit for the experience, **build it and use it the way the instructions tell you**.  Your circuit appears to be come from the You Tube channel "Kasyan", which is an adaptation of Danyk.cz's circuit.

Kasyan builds on a single-sided PCB (indeed, his channel has lots of PCB manufacturer ads), and Danyk builds on "raw copper board", which is quite common for high-voltage and radio experimenters.

This is from Kasyan's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wsVshsJ11o)
[image]

This is from Danyk.cz [circuit](https://danyk.cz/noteb_en.html).
[image]

Comment: Yes
Lots of schematics and circuits from buck-boost and based on UC3843
Only my input is 27V 15A
And I need 45 volts and finally 7 amps in boost mode
The Buck mode is from 3 volts to...
At first, the whole circuit was on the PCB and it was soldered carefully and orderly, and I thickened the parts that bear a lot of load.
I found a schematic that many videos and circuits were based on and tried to assemble it exactly
But this is a mystery that in all cases (changing the value of resistors, capacitors and even inductors)
The problem is the same
Thank you

Comment: Where you are running at 16 kHz, the ON time is about 20 uSec, and with 27 V into a 10 uH inductor, that is 54 A peak current. That inductor will definitely saturate, and the overcurrent trip will certainly trip. The waveform on the sense resistor is mostly garbage, so hard to determine actual current.

Comment: @PStechPaul - Thank you very much for your help
The inductor does not get hot in any way, is it possible to get saturated and not get hot?
I will also check about the frequency
Thank you very much for your help
The inductor does not get hot in any way, is it possible to get saturated and not get hot?
I will also check about the frequency.
In addition, I have also tested the 40 μH inductor, the problem is still the heating of the MOSFET and the voltage drop.

Comment: You really need to either greatly improve the layout, or make a proper PC board. It may be that the MOSFET is not remaining on because the voltage on the sense resistor R10 is rising enough to reduce the gate voltage. This will be a problem if the resistor has significant inductance. Also your cheap scope is probably limited to a bandwidth of 100 kHz or so, and won't be able to display high frequency components like sharp transitions and oscillations.

Comment: @PStechPaul - Thankful
By the way, I have reduced the resistance value of R10, that is, 0.025 Ohm
And my voltage drop decreased
Maybe this article will influence the guidance.
In the specifications of the oscilloscope, it was written that it supports 0 to 200 kHz.
This heating of the MOSFET unfortunately does not allow checking the circuit while the load is connected to it.